# No, I haven't already raised this flag (not here, anyway)

Tags: support, flags, flag-dialog

So for whatever reason I was going through [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) looking for questions that had slipped through the retag/migrate net. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692301/blocked-from-answer-on-stackoverflow), which clearly didn't belong on SO, and probably would be migration-rejected here due to low quality; however, I can't custom-close-vote (not enough rep), and flags don't have a custom option. I flagged it for migration in the hope that it would be processed correctly.

I then came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379157/why-is-the-year-not-displayed-in-the-questions-and-comments-dates), and decided to use the same tactic -

> [image: "you have already raised this flag"]

No, I haven't! (Apologies for the poor freehand-circle quality; the Surface RT is not very conducive to drawing them.)

Have I done something wrong and been covertly banned from raising close flags? Is there a new one-outstanding-close-flag limit? Is there a new no-more-close-flags-while-you-have-an-outstanding-migration-flag limit? Is this just a plain old bug?

---

**Update**: Turns out I flagged it two weeks ago, and the flag was still waiting for review. **facepalm**

Comment: +1 for freehand circle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the flag history, you flagged that question for closure on July 5th.

It was just marked as helpful moments ago when someone voted to close it.

So... don't see any problems.