# Misleading text in flag dialog - "you have already raised this flag" when I didn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

[image: screenshot]

Now, I raised "duplicate" flag. And I don't argue with the fact that "another reason" should be disabled. But the text should be different, as I didn't raise any "another reason" flags on this question.

The text under the second option shown is untrue, but it may be OK to leave both messages identical. Just make them:

> you have already raised a flag from the same moderation queue

Of course my wording may be less than perfect, it's the general idea. That way it will be true without any changes in code.

Comment: The same thing happens with spam and offensive flags because they both end up in the same queue

Comment: @RichardTingle so maybe text should be like "You have already raise flag from this family"? Only with better wording ;)

Comment: I agree it is not a bug, but just something that needs worded better.  You can only raise flags in the same "family" once and since duplicate and close flags are in the same family... you can't even vote to close a post you previously flagged for closure.  So it is [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Molot in my opinion better change this into feature request asking to change the wording.

Comment: @psubsee2003 are untrue messages not a bugs? For me they are.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but the text isn't ambiguous. It's simply false - I did not raise this flag and I'm told I did. I agree it's a minor issue and I agree it should be corrected at the text level, but why false message isn't a bug?

Comment: @Mołot but it is not an untrue message.  It is absolutely true.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I did not raise any "it should be closed for another reason" flag. Message says I did. How the message is absolutely true?

Comment: @Mołot unfortunately we won't agree on this.  I believe the message is ambiguous at worst and deserves a "feature-request" to change it.  You obviously feel differently.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ambiguous? How can "you have" be more clear and less ambiguous? It's a simple boolean value. In message, value of "have you?" is set to TRUE when in reality it's FALSE. That's simple facts. What does it have to do with feelings?

Comment: @Mołot you are focusing on "you have", I am focusing on "this flag".  "This" is a bad word to use in many cases, especially in technical writing, because it is ambiguous without a descriptive noun.  What is "this"?  In this case, "this" means a close flag, but you are interpreting it to mean "this specific item".  That is why I say it is ambiguous.

Comment: @psubsee2003 In bugreport I'm focusing on the part that's buggy, of course :) The fact that flags cannot be raised is OK and I stated it in my question. I'll try to clarify this. By Wiktionary "this" means "the (thing) here" - it's natural language usage to assume it's about the very item it appears in, doesn't it? Or maybe we should move this discussion to [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)?..

Comment: @Molot let me explain with personal experience. All my life (well, ever since I learned English) I was sure that sentence like "Jon, Arynn, and Jason" is wrong and should be "Jon, Arynn and Jason". Until I posted [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199097/152859) and learned something new about comma, Oxford, and Stalin. Same applies here: "this flag" in Stack Exchange-ish means "this **type of** flag". :)

Comment: Saying the above, I do agree it can be worded better, hence my initial suggestion to ask for rewording.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think that messages not written in clear English or untrue are bugs. If someone will edit it to feature request, I'll ask to disassociate my account from this post. Having that said, I clarified it a bit to show that rewording would be good enough solution for me.

Comment: @Mołot each and his own. Good luck!

Comment: I wish to eat a dinosaur --> You have already eaten this food. No I haven't! I've eaten meat, is that what "this" means?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with the next deploy, that text will instead read `you have already raised this type of flag`; which is what the check really is there.