# Why does the flagging dialogue think I've raised a flag I haven't?

Tags: bug, flags

[image: Screenshot of flagging dialogue]

The flagging dialogue tells me that I have raised a duplicate flag on that question. I haven't. I flagged it as off topic because instead of inline code it relied on a link (now broken).

Comment: *Raided* in the title is a typo. But I like it, so I'm leaving it.

Comment: _this type_ - duplicate flag is a type of off-topic flag.

Comment: Related: [Misleading text in flag dialog - “you have already raised this flag” when I didn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199188/misleading-text-in-flag-dialog-you-have-already-raised-this-flag-when-i-didn).

Comment: Ah, that's actually a very very near duplicate, @psubsee2003. I suppose it depends on how you interpret the word *type*.

Comment: Duplicate and Off-Topic are both closing type flags; you already flagged the post.

Comment: The comment used to say "You have already raised this flag", but "..type of..." was added to avoid confusion because duplicates and closed for other reasons are both the same type of flag.

Comment: @TRiG it is partially a dup.  I didn't close as such because the answer is in the comments not the answer.  The related post is a feature request to fix the misleading comment

Comment: @psubsee2003 So they do listen, I remember discussing that on one of the many duplicates of this

Comment: @RichardTingle it would appear so.  I think your question is a better dup, but I believe it needs an answer to reflect the new message.  Since you found the dup, you can have the honors.

Comment: And here I was, happy with [meta-tag:status-completed] on [my report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199188), sure confusion about this message is dealt with and gone...

Comment: So the wording was changed to avoid confusion, but doesn't actually avoid confusion. I'll accept that this is a dupe, and am happy for it to be closed as such, but I'll try to think of better wording and open a new question suggesting it.

Comment: @Mołot unfortunately I don't think it is a perfect solution as long as duplicate and closed for other reasons are separate in the flag dialog.  The current message after your report is was the best solution but still means someone needs to know that duplicate and close flags are the same type.

Comment: @psubsee2003 My request was for "the same moderation queue", team chosen to use something a bit different... I think it is better than it was, but it seems there is a room for improvement.

Comment: @Mołot unfortunately I don't think that will eliminate the confusion, since it means you need to know duplicates and close votes go to the same moderation queue.

Comment: Ultimately that knowledge only comes once you can handle the flags yourself, after which you don't raise flags anymore

Comment: @psubsee2003 I was learning on an older dialog, when duplicates was on a close reasons list. Now? True for new users it may be not so normal. As I also wrote in my original question, I'm not the best one with human-related texts :(

Comment: @Mołot the new flag dialog stresses dups before other close reason (which I think is an ok idea because questions should be closed as dups regardless of other problems if there is a dup), so as long as it does that and duplicates are considered "closing", there is no clear fix that can be expressed in a short phrase.

Comment: "I flagged it as off topic because of the broken link." 

Did that make sense to you when you did it? Don't abuse the flag system.

Comment: @GEOCHET. The question is of the form "Why doesn't my website work?" With a broken link, it ceases to be a question. My flag reason was the http://sscce.org/ one.