# Flagging a post for the second time brings up a different screen

Tags: discussion, support, bug, flags

Usually when I flag any question once and I try to flag that question again, I get a screen like below.
 [image]

But today when I try to flag a question for the second time I did not got that screen, rather I got the normal screen for "flag question" and both flags are accepted as helpful; see below image.

[image]

So I am confused whether this is normal behavior, or did something strange happen to me today?

Comment: Look at the screenshot you posted. Even though the duplicate flag was raised by you, you still get the option to flag it as *very low quality*, and that is what has happened. You flagged a question twice with those 2 flags and both were deemed helpful.

Comment: That's what i am asking it is possible that we can flag more then once for same question.?

Comment: Then the simple answer is, *Yes*, it is possible to flag a post more than once, but the type of flags would be different. I'm not getting the link to the post regarding this but am sure is there somewhere. Hopefully someone coming along would it :) JFYI, this post is going to be marked as `status-bydesign` mostly.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199188/225745 - as you can see in the moderator's answer, there are a different kinds of flags.