# Show you have flagged a post in the flag dialogue window

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, flag-dialog

When I vote to close a question and I open back up the dialogue window it will say

> You voted to close this question {time} ago

which is fair enough.

However, if I flag a post I will get told

> You have already flagged this post for moderator attention

**only after** I try and submit a second flag. I think it would be helpful to display

> You flagged this post as {reason}, {time} ago

if I open the dialogue box again.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212784/162102

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is already implemented. Not sure what step you have followed but here is the flag dialog that I received on clicking the *flag* link after raising a flag:

> [image]

The message shows **you have already raised this type of flag** and I didn't had to submit the dialog to get this message.

Comment: Really?  I have never seen that.

Comment: I haven't seen that before and that doesn't show for me.

Comment: I tried it on a site where I don't have _close privileges_.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196619/duplicate-flag-lists-you-have-already-raised-this-flag-after-flagging-as-uncl and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199188/misleading-text-in-flag-dialog-you-have-already-raised-this-flag-when-i-didn