# Suggestion, change "This Type of Flag" to something less ambiguous

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, wording

A constant source of confusion is the wording on the menu for flagging a question or answer.

In 2013 it seems it was first changed from `this flag` to `this type of flag` ([Duplicate flag lists "you have already raised this flag" after flagging as "Unclear what you're asking"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196619/duplicate-flag-lists-you-have-already-raised-this-flag-after-flagging-as-uncl) ), but that is still not enough, based on the number of questions here on Meta.SE and on individual stacks' metas regarding it.

Recently on M&TV for example: [Why is it telling me that I flagged a question as a duplicate when I didn't?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/why-is-it-telling-me-that-i-flagged-a-question-as-a-duplicate-when-i-didnt/2188?noredirect=1#comment7774_2188)

`This type of flag` can be read as ***THIS*** type of flag, or this ***TYPE*** of flag. Obviously the implied meaning is the latter, but many people think its the former.

I suggest that the wording be changed to a less ambiguous one. Specifically, I suggest it be changed to:

> ***You have already raised `a similar` type of flag***.

Change `this` to `a similar` would be specific enough to let people know it doesn't mean that specific type of flag, just a generally similar type.

A wordier version would have both, `this or a similar`.

Comment: We are working on a series of improvements to the flag dialog which includes clarifying this sentence, but no changes have been made to it yet.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as the flag dialog now unambiguously shows you the type of flag that you have raised.

> [image]